# UIToolBar button not positioning correctly after increasing height

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

Well the problem is well understood in the image below , so I'm trying to increase height of the `UIToolBar` but the buttons aren't aligning correctly to the toolbar. Is there any solution for it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because the button will start their drawing from the top, so it will move lower once you start increasing the height of the button, since the text will be in the middle.

I am pretty sure there is no way to solve this.

EDIT:
I found a way you can set the text:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 5.0f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Use the offset to change the location for the text

Answer (score 0):

The little solution i found is to use UIButton instead of UIBarButton.
UIButton will align correctly to the UIToolBar(with/without changed height).
[image]